# Java console application

Tags: java

Can you tell me if the console example (Java) below seems correct and how can I test it myself?
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=79
I get about 8 errors, starting with:

> "Severity and Description Path    Resource    Location    Creation Time   Id The
>   method printf(String, Object[]) in the type Console is not applicable
>   for the arguments (String, String)    JL1 Console6.java   line
>   21    1345812238329   351"

for this line:

```
console.printf("Welcome, %1$s.", username);
```

I wrote a lot of applets, they all worked fine, up until I tried this.

Before this I tried a very simple console that read a few words until encountering the word 'bye', and it worked.
My Java version: 1.6.0_33
OS: Windows 7

Comment: It works fine for me... sounds like your JDK isn't handling varargs properly. How are you compiling?

Comment: @Sam The fact that `System.out.println(String, ...)` doesn't work either could well confirm that your JDK isn't handling varargs properly. How are you compiling the code?

Comment: I just created a class, pasted that code in, saved the changes and the next step I did: Ran as Java application. However I see all those errors. Yes, I think it might have to do with that as I saw a warning in that sense. How can I have the varargs handled properly? Thank you!

Comment: @Sam If you are using Eclipse check the JDK version. Maybe you are compiling with the wrong version.

Comment: Is that in Eclipse? I'd check the project properties to see if anything looks amiss, although I'm not really good enough to be able to say what could be up. Could you try running `javac` on the file directly from the commandline?

Comment: I use Java version: 1.6.0_33 OS: Windows 7. Yes, I use Eclipse. I'll try that and get back

Comment: I tried this in cmd: javac Console6.java (after cd/changing direction to be placed in the correct folder). The error I get is: javac is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
main(String... aArgs)
```

seems to be incorrect.
You can try with

```
main(String args[])
```

You may still face problems . You can give the error messages for further answers.